# Deleting unused drupal core modules

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

Is it okay to delete unused drupal core modules? I have almost 20 such core modules that are not being used... will they have any impact on performance of the site?

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/53331/safe-to-remove-core-optional-modules/53333#53333

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it won't have until you haven't enabled them.

But I won't suggest you to delete any core module whether it's used or not. If it doesn't have any impact on deleting then there is no impact on keeping too..because those hooks are not going to be called in page load..

Then the core module stays in default folder of Drupal install, so there is no chance for you to get confuse too with the contributed ones which would be in sites/all/modules

Comment: From a security point of view it is not a bad practice. Instead of managing the access rights to disable the execution of these files (remember that the php file is still there) you could delete them and be carefree on exploits for these modules. Many of the exploits use modules on cms that the application isn't aware of nor needs them.

Comment: I believe, if we go to update core and some of the core module is deleted..there can be some problem(though I have never felt in some situation like this where I have deleted core modules and updated core)..
But updating core is usual practice in case of Drupal..isn't it? Otherwise there are security risks...

Comment: Absolutely, all updates to drupal core should be installed as soon as possible. And truth is that deleting core modules could produce problems with the updates, though I am not 100% sure that is the case.

Comment: Yes & that was the first thing came in mind when I saw this question...that what would happen when he delete core modules & update..
Deleting core module should never done for those site which we are planning to keep for some long time...

Answer (score 4):

No you won't see any performance improvements, save perhaps a few milliseconds on the module admin page.

The next time you update Drupal those module files will be replaced anyway so it's an exercise in futility really.

And please, [think of the kittens](http://www.flickr.com/photos/hagengraf/2802915470/).